Weinberg's treatment of bosons and fermions
I am reading the chapter on The Cluster Decomposition Principle from Weinberg's The Quantum Theory of Fields volume 1 and having some trouble understanding one of his arguments after eq. (4.1.2) from section 4.1 titled Bosons and Fermions . Under exchange of identical species of particles (labelled by $n$) with respective 3-momenta $\mathbf{p},\mathbf{p}'$ and spin $\sigma,\sigma'$, we have
\begin{equation}
\Phi_{\cdots \,\mathbf{p}\, \sigma\, n\, \cdots\, \mathbf{p}'\,\sigma'\, n\,\cdots} = \alpha_n\, \Phi_{\cdots\, \mathbf{p}'\, \sigma'\, n\, \cdots\, \mathbf{p}\,\sigma\, n\,\cdots}\,
\end{equation}
where $\alpha_n$ must be a phase since these two states describe the same physical system and hence must belong to the same ray. When the phase $\alpha_n$ depends only on the particle species we can swap the particles twice to see $\alpha_n^2 = 1\implies \alpha_n = \pm 1$. This is what we know from undergraduate Quantum Mechanics.
However, after this, Weinberg argues why the factor $\alpha_n$ cannot have any dependence on the particle spins. He says that this would cause the phases $\alpha_n$ to form a 1D representation of the rotation group in 3 dimensions and therefore is the trivial representation.
I did not understand why this must be true. Since we are swapping the two particles by rotation, this would also mean that the other particles have changed their positions. Or, is this rotation in some 'space' of particle labels only acting on the species $n$? But still wouldn't the other particles also change their position?
In his textbook on QM titled Lectures on Quantum Mechanics, section 4.5 titled Bosons and Fermions he explains in footnote 14 that such a dependence would be physically inconsistent with invariance under rotations or transformations to moving coordinate systems.
I am very confused. Can someone please explain?
Edit: I think this statement is better written with the 'rotation group' replaced by the 'permutation group'? 1-dimensional representations of the permutation group are the trivial representation and the signed representation (depending on the sign of the permutation).

I'd recommend that you find a totally different argument, maybe by a different text. This particular thing is the spin-statistics theorem, not cluster decomposition principle, so the argument seems a bit weird as it is.

@naturallyInconsistent just to be clear, do you mean Weinberg's argument is a bit weird? And that I should find a different text to look at?
Or, did you mean my argument to 'understand' Weinberg is incorrect?

I had to rush home and break out my copy to confirm: It is both. Apparently he chose not to cover spin-stats at all. But you are also being weird to think that this has anything to do with the rotation of other quantities. We are NOT swapping the particles by rotation. This is a discrete swap, closer to mirror reflection.

@naturallyInconsistent wouldn't it be better to call it just a swap as mirror reflection would change the positions of the other particles, too? So in this sense, this is just a permutation?

Weinberg writes: "The phase $\alpha_n$ cannot have any non-trivial dependence on the spins of the two particles that are interchanged because then these spin-dependent phase factors would have to furnish a representation of the rotation group, and there are no non-trivial representations of the three-dimensional rotation group that are one-dimensional- that is, by phase factors." I think what he means is that the groups describing spin are homomorphic to SO(3) so the alphas would have to be able to represent SO(3) and they can't so there's no spin dependence but it's not well explained.

"The Conceptual Framework of Quantum Field Theory" by Anthony Duncan has clearer explanations.
